# Insight on Conic Section

Tags: geometry

Sorry...the name may be misleading a bit. But I have some questions on conic sections. I have given my approach for each for the questions,

1) Give an example of two conics which intersect each other at a single point.

My Approach: We take two parabolas, $y=ax^2+bx+c$ and $y=px^2+qx+c$, then equate both of them, we get a quadratic equation in $x$, now  both the parabolas intersect at one point if and only if the quadratic equation in $x$, has coincident roots. (is this reasoning correct?) Also apart from two parabolas, which two conics also satisfy the above properties?

2) Let $A(x_1,y_1,z_1)$, $B(x_2,y_2,z_2)$ and $C(x_3,y_3,z_3)$ be the vertices of a triangle.Find the angle between the line $BC$ and the line passing through the midpoint of $AB$ and $AC$. What do you conclude from this?

My Approach: Is there any elegant way to solve this,or we have to go for a brute force solution of finding the equation of both the lines and then calculate the angle between both of them.

Please help me out. And thanks in advance...

Comment: Even simpler: $y=ax^2$ and $y=bx^2$, $a<>b$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach to intersection of two conic sections(parabola, ellipse... Whatever it is...) is exactly correct. The motto is: Solve the equations together and try to get the solution out of it!

For the triangle question... First calculate $|AB|$, $|AC|$ and $|BC|$(recall the distance between two points) and then apply [law of cosines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_theorem)... Of course some other approaches might help depending on questions.

Comment: For question 1: Can you think of any two other conics!! Just asking??

Comment: Yes. Why not? Just pick two *arbitrary* conic sections. Let us say a parabola and an ellipse. You  just use again the same principle: Solve their equations simultaneously.

Comment: Hmm...I get it.The motto is: Solve the equations together and try to get the solution out of it!